# Supress logging to console on next(err) method in express

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  const err = new Error('Test');
  next(err);
});
```

express will log the error and stacktrace to the console. Is there a way that I can suppress the logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an error handler middleware in your Express implementation to handle the `next(err)` call like this:

```
// defined as the last route
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
});
```

then, Express won't log any error and you can control what response is sent for the error.

I'd suggest reading this page on Express error handling: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html.

---

If you look in the express code where this logging comes from, it comes from [this code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/lib/application.js#L628):

```
function logerror(err) {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (this.get('env') !== 'test') console.error(err.stack || err.toString());
}
```

which curiously enough shows that if you do this:

```
app.set('env', 'test');
```

or you set `NODE_ENV=test` in the environment before launching your server, then it will skip the error logging too.  But, it's much better to just control things with your own error handler as I show about where you can also control what type of response is sent.

Comment: I was already using a custom error handler, but in my instance I was still calling next(err) within it after it sends the request back out. I apparently only need to call the nex(err) method if the headers have already been sent?

Comment: @Reed - You call `next()` when you want to continue to more route handlers.  If you've sent the response, you don't want to continue further routing (so don't want to call `next()`) and certainly in your own error handler where you've dealt with the error and sent a response you don't want to call `next()` because that will then then hit the default error handler and try to send another response and do the logging.

Comment: That makes sense, it's just a little misleading because the example they provide has a next(err) method called in the Default Error Handler section.